# Summary of values across rows and columns in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like:

```
Group   A    B    C    D
XYZ     4    Na   1    3
XYZ     Na   2    2    1
DEF     4    3    2    1
DEF     3    3    1    1
PQR     1    Na   Na   1
PQR     3    2    2    4
```

I want the summary of this dataset across rows and columns for the count of each value as below:

```
Group   4    3    2    1
XYZ     1    1    2    2
DEF     1    3    1    3
PQR     1    1    2    2
```

The count of 4 in the dataset for group XYZ across all rows and columns is 1, for 2 and 1 its 2, for 3 its 1. I can do this by creating 4 new columns 4,3,2,1 and getting the count row wise and then column wise, but this is not efficient and scalable. I am sure there is a better way to get this done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `reshape2` package we can `melt` and `dcast` as follows,

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(na.omit(melt(df, id.vars = 'Group')), Group ~ value, fun.aggregate = length)
#  Group 1 2 3 4
#1   DEF 3 1 3 1
#2   PQR 2 2 1 1
#3   XYZ 2 2 1 1
```

Answer (score 4):

This uses no packages and is just one line.  Here `DF$Group[row(DF[-1])]` is a Group labels vector such that each element corresponds to the unravelled numeric vector `unlist(DF[-1])`.

```
table(DF$Group[row(DF[-1])], unlist(DF[-1]))
```

giving:

```
      1 2 3 4
  DEF 3 1 3 1
  PQR 2 2 1 1
  XYZ 2 2 1 1
```

If the order of rows and columns shown in the question is important then to we can create factors from each of the two `table` arguments with the factor levels being defined in the orders desired.  In this case we use the following line instead of the line of code above:

```
table(Group = factor(DF$Group[row(DF[-1])], unique(DF$Group)), factor(unlist(DF[-1]), 4:1))
```

giving:

```
Group 4 3 2 1
  XYZ 1 1 2 2
  DEF 1 3 1 3
  PQR 1 1 2 2
```

The above produces an object of class `"table"`.  This is a particularly suitable class for tabulated frequencies.  For example, once in this form `ftable` can be used to easily rearrange it further as in `ftable(tab, row.vars = 2)` or `ftable(tab, row.vars = 1:2)` where `tab` is the above computed table.

If a data.frame were preferred then convert it like this:

```
cbind(Group = rownames(tab), as.data.frame.matrix(tab))
```

The input data.frame `DF` is defined reproducibly in Note 2 at the end.

**Alternatives**

Although the above seems the most direct here are some other alternatives that also use no packages:

**1) by** For each set of rows having the same `Group` value the anonymous function creates a data.frame identifying the Group, converting the columns other than the first to a factor with the indicated levels and running `table` to get the counts.  The `"by"` list that is returned is sorted back to the original order and we `rbind` everything back together.

```
do.call("rbind",
   by(DF, DF$Group, function(x) {
      data.frame(Group = x[1,1], 
                 as.list(table(factor(unlist(x[, -1]), levels = 4:1))), 
                 check.names = FALSE)
   })[unique(DF$Group)])
```

giving:

```
    Group 4 3 2 1
XYZ   XYZ 1 1 2 2
DEF   DEF 1 3 1 3
PQR   PQR 1 1 2 2
```

**1a)** This slightly shorter variation would also work.  It returns a matrix identifying the groups using row names.

```
kount <- function(x) table(factor(unlist(x), levels = 4:1))
m <- do.call("rbind", by(DF[, -1], DF$Group, kount)[unique(DF$Group)])
```

giving:

```
> m
    4 3 2 1
XYZ 1 1 2 2
DEF 1 3 1 3
PQR 1 1 2 2
```

**2) outer**

```
gps <- unique(DF$Group)
levs <- 4:1
kount2 <- function(g, lv) sum(subset(DF, Group == g)[-1] == lv, na.rm = TRUE)
m <- outer(gps, levs, Vectorize(kount2))
dimnames(m) <- list(gps, levs))
```

giving this matrix:

```
> m
    4 3 2 1
XYZ 1 1 2 2
DEF 1 3 1 3
PQR 1 1 2 2
```

**3) sapply**

```
kount3 <- function(g) table(factor(unlist(DF[DF$Group == g, -1]), levels = 4:1))
gps <- as.character(unique(DF$Group))
do.call("rbind", sapply(gps, kount3, simplify = FALSE))
```

giving:

```
    4 3 2 1
XYZ 1 1 2 2
DEF 1 3 1 3
PQR 1 1 2 2
```

**4) aggregate**

```
aggregate(1:nrow(DF), DF["Group"],  function(ix) 
  table(factor(unlist(DF[ix, -1]), levels = 4:1)))[unique(DF$Group), ]
```

giving:

```
  Group x.4 x.3 x.2 x.1
3   XYZ   1   1   2   2
1   DEF   1   3   1   3
2   PQR   1   1   2   2
```

**5) tapply**

```
do.call("rbind", tapply(1:nrow(DF), DF$Group, function(ix)
       table(factor(unlist(DF[ix, -1]), levels = 4:1))))[unique(DF$Group), ]
```

**6) reshape**

```
with(reshape(DF, dir = "long", varying = list(2:5)), 
  table(factor(Group, unique(DF$Group)), factor(A, 4:1)))
```

giving:

```
    4 3 2 1
XYZ 1 1 2 2
DEF 1 3 1 3
PQR 1 1 2 2
```

**Note 1:**  (1a), (2), (3), (5) and (6) produce a matrix or table result with groups as row names.  If you prefer a data frame with Groups as a column then supposing that `m` is the matrix, add this:

```
data.frame(Group = rownames(m), m, check.names = FALSE)
```

**Note 2:**  The input `DF` in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "Group   A    B    C    D
XYZ     4    Na   1    3
XYZ     Na   2    2    1
DEF     4    3    2    1
DEF     3    3    1    1
PQR     1    Na   Na   1
PQR     3    2    2    4"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, na.strings = "Na")
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `dplyr/tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
    mutate_each(funs(replace(., .=="Na", NA))) %>% 
    gather(Var, Val, A:D, na.rm=TRUE) %>%
    group_by(Group, Val) %>% 
    tally() %>%
    spread(Val, n)
#    Group   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`
#* <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1   DEF     3     1     3     1
#2   PQR     2     2     1     1
#3   XYZ     2     2     1     1
```